# Serialize .NET Dictionary<string, string> into JSON Key Value Pair Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, json

I need to get:

```
public class Package
{
    public Package()
    {
        name = "";
        type = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
    }

    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> type { get; set; }
}
```

into:

```
{
    "name":"package_name",
    "type":
    {
        "http://random.url.as.key":"random/value"
    }
}
```

with:

```
Package package = new Package();
package.name = "package_name";
package.type.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "http://random.url.as.key", "random/value" } });
```

I get:

```
{
    "name":"package_name",
    "type":
    [
        [
            {
                "Key":"http:\/\/random.url.as.key",
                "Value":"random\/value"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

while, with:

```
var package = new
{
    name = "package_name",
    type = new
    {
        http_random_url_as_key = "random/value"
    }
};
```

I get:

```
{
    "name":"package_name",
    "type":
    {
        "http_random_url_as_key":"random/value"
    }
}
```

I can't get the obsure *http://random.url.as.key* that I need. I have tried using JavaScriptSerializer, DataContractJsonSerializer, *and* Custom Convertor for Json.NET, all with limited success/shortcomings.

There must be a better way/something I'm overlooking to get a simple JSON Object over the wire!

Comment: what are you using to serialize into JSON?

Comment: You first `Package` class won't compile. And are you sure the field *type* is a `List<Dictionary<string,string>>`? It seems that you want it to perform like a `Dictionary<string,string>` when converting to JSON.

Comment: Use this to serialize the .net code to JSON and revert back. http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx

Comment: This post can help you in your problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/36223340/1442180

Answer (score 47):

Well, first off, for the first example, what you basically have is a list of collections of `KeyValuePair<string,string>` objects.

So, the reason that it gets converted to the JSON shown is this:

```
{
    "name":"package_name",
    "type":
    [ // List<Dictionary<string,string>>
        [ // Dictionary<string,string>, a list of KeyValuePair<string,string> objects
            { // KeyValuePair<string,string> object 
                "Key":"http:\/\/random.url.as.key",
                "Value":"random\/value"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

As far as your second example, you are creating a dynamic object, containing a dynamic object, and each of the object's fields are what are providing the key value.

So, I would suggest ditching the outer `List<>` around the `Dictionary<string,string>`, then make use of the `Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.KeyValuePairConverter` object in the JSON.Net library when doing your serialization:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( package, new KeyValuePairConverter( ) );
```

Hope that helps.

**EDIT**

Okay, so I figured I should give a more concrete example

```
public class Package
{
    public Package()
    {
        name = "";
        type = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public string name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> type { get; set; }
}

Package package = new Package();
package.name = "package_name";
package.type.Add("http://random.url.as.key", "random/value");
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( package, new KeyValuePairConverter( ) );
```

This will get you the output

```
{
    "name":"package_name",
    "type":
    {
        "http://random.url.as.key":"random/value"
    }
}
```

Comment: If I want to have both wcf and json endpoints, how would this code fit?

Comment: Usage of `KeyValuePairConverter` is exactly what i need. Thanks!