# Deserialize KeyValuePair<string, string> Json.Net

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I need to deserialize a `string` like this

```
{
  "example": {
    "id": "12345",
    "name": "blabla"
  }
}
```

into a `KeyValuePair<string, string>` or something similiar.

I tried:

```
var pair = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<KeyValuePair<string, string>>(d["example"].ToString());
```

(`d["example"]` returns the json string like shown above)

The result was an empty `KeyValuePair<string, string>`.

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124889/serialize-net-dictionarystring-string-into-json-key-value-pair-object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string json = 
     @"{
          ""example"": {
          ""id"": ""12345"",
          ""name"": ""blabla""
          }
        }";

var jobj =  JObject.Parse(json);
var dict = jobj["example"]
            .Children().Cast<JProperty>()
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => (string)x.Value);
```

or

```
var dict = jobj["example"].ToObject<Dictionary<string, string>>();
```