# WCF is serializing dictionary into JSON array instead of list

Tags: c#, json, wcf

As a basic example of my situation, lets say I have a class (UserInfo) with two properties. One is Username string, the other named Demographics is a dictionary. The class is marked with DataContract and the props are marked with DataMember. I have an OperationContract in my WCF service that returns my object as JSON. When a request hits and my object is returned it is being serialized as:

```
{"UserName":"Bobby", "Demographics" : [{"Key": "1", "Value": "Blah1"},{"Key": "2", "Value": "Blah2"}]}
```

The Demographics is being returned as an array. I want it to be returned as a list. Meaning the bracket should be removed, like this:

**EDIT** I wrote that object incorrectly

`{"Username": "Bobby",
  "Demographics": {
    "Key1": {
      "Value": "Blah1"
    },
    "Key2": {
      "Value": "Blah2"
    }
  }
}`

My operation contract is:
    `[OperationContract]
            [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "GetNewUserFields",
                       ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                       Method = "GET"),
            Description("Get the Fields needed for a new user")]
            UserInfo GetNewUserFields();`

Is there any way to do this? I would post direct code example, however the classes that I am serializing are actually much more complex than what I have described and the return result posted here would be a mess of data to sift through.

Thank you for any help that you may provide.

Comment: The JSON you want to return is not a valid JSON structure. You can't just nest an object inside an object without a key.

Comment: You are correct. I am a knucklehead. I edited the above to be correct.

Comment: In that case have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124889/serialize-net-dictionarystring-string-into-json-key-value-pair-object

Comment: So it looks like I will have to use the JsonConvert to serialize rather than using the built in. Which leads to needing to return a stream. Round about way of getting there, but it works. Thank you much!