# Create Object from dictionary with Json

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, dictionary

**How to serialize Dictionary to json object**

```
 var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"Username", "{Username}"},
            {"FirstName", "{FirstName}"},
            {"LastName", "{LastName}"},
            {"AccountMeta[0].MetaKey", "Pincode"},
            {"AccountMeta[0].MetaValue", "150000"},

        };
public class Account {
    public string Username {get;set;}
    public string FirstName{get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    public List<AccountMeta> AccountMeta {get;set;}
}
```

And Objects:

```
public class AccountMeta{
     public string MetaKey {get;set;}
     public string MetaValue{get;set;}
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serialize .NET Dictionary<string, string> into JSON Key Value Pair Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124889/serialize-net-dictionarystring-string-into-json-key-value-pair-object)

Comment: It's not duplicate. AccountMeta is List.
AccountMeta[0].MetaKey
AccountMeta[1].MetaKey

Comment: @GiviBibileishvili so you want to serialize a list into a dictionary?

Comment: @alstonp No i wont to create account object from this dictionary. Dictionary contains list accountmeta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the library **Newtonsoft.Json** [here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Manages serialization of any kind of objects gracefully and its free.

The Json format provides an standard way to serialize arrays and neasted objects, and it doesn't support for object paths. So your aproach for serializing Lists as `"List[index]" = "value"` and object properties as `"Object.Property" = "Value"` style would not work

Install the package:  `Newtonsoft.Json`
Example of use:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = ...;
string Json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary);

MyClass Result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass >();
```