# Newtonsoft.Json, Populate Dictionary failed

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, serialization, json.net

I serialize a dictionary to json by Newtonsoft.json and bellow code :

```
var serializeSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
            TypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full,
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented
        };
        var serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dic, serializeSettings);
```

this code generate a json like this :

```
{
  "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
  "9648af76-7986-4b34-8b2c-97b2345769ef": "Test"
}
```

I try to deserialize json to dictionary by this code :

```
var newDic = new Dictionay<Guid,string>();
var deserializeSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
    TypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full,
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented
}
JsonConvert.PopulateObject(serializedObject, newDic, deserializeSettings);
```

But this exception occurs :

> Could not convert string '$type' to dictionary key type 'System.Guid'. Create a TypeConverter to convert from the string to the key type object. Path '$type', line 2, position 10.
>
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateDictionary(IDictionary dictionary, JsonReader reader, JsonDictionaryContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id)
>
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Populate(JsonReader reader, Object target)
>
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.PopulateInternal(JsonReader reader, Object target)
>
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Populate(JsonReader reader, Object target)
>
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.PopulateObject(String value, Object target, JsonSerializerSettings settings)

I write GuidConverter like this and use it. but not work

```
public class GuidConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Guid));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        try
        {
            return serializer.Deserialize<Guid>(reader);
        }
        catch
        {
            return Guid.Empty;
        }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I found my problem. Change code to deserialize json to Dictionary< string, string > and now First item in generated dictionary is :

```
Kay: "$type"
Value : "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
```

**Why??**

Comment: Do you need the dspecial setting and the Guid?  Maybe try something simpler like `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dic);` and see if that gives you what you need.

Comment: @senschen I use a generic class to serialize and deserialize multiple types in my project. other types in my project needs to this settings.
please read last edit of my question

Comment: Use string instead of Guid @Fred

Comment: @ZehraSubaş In last edit of my question I do it,but ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The problem** is that you have specified [`TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_TypeNameHandling.htm) when serializing your dictionary.  This causes a metadata `"$type"` property to be emitted as the first object in the dictionary:

> ```
> {
>   "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
>   "9648af76-7986-4b34-8b2c-97b2345769ef": "Test"
> }
> ```

When deserializing using [`DeserializeObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm), this token is normally consumed by Json.NET when the corresponding c# object is constructed.  But you are using [`PopulateObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PopulateObject.htm) on a pre-allocated dictionary.  Thus the metadata property is not consumed during construction and instead Json.NET tries to add it to the dictionary, and fails.

**The solution** is to set [`MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.ReadAhead`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_MetadataPropertyHandling.htm) in `deserializeSettings`.  Doing so will cause the `"$type"` property to be consumed or ignored (as appropriate) unconditionally:

```
var deserializeSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
    TypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full,
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
    MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.ReadAhead
};
JsonConvert.PopulateObject(serializedObject, newDic, deserializeSettings);
```

Please note that, from the [release notes](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2014/04/30/json-net-6-0-release-3-serialize-all-the-f), *there is a slight cost in memory usage and speed* from using this setting.

**Alternatively**, if you don't unconditionally need metadata type information in your JSON, you could serialize with `TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto` and only emit type information for polymorphic types, which your `Dictionary<Guid, string>` is not.

**Relatedly**, when using `TypeNameHandling`, do take note of this caution from the [Newtonsoft docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm):

> TypeNameHandling should be used with caution when your application deserializes JSON from an external source. Incoming types should be validated with a custom SerializationBinder when deserializing with a value other than None.

For a discussion of why this may be necessary, see *[TypeNameHandling caution in Newtonsoft Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39565954/3744182)*.